# не работает set()

Tags: python, list, set

я хочу сделать проверку на повторяющиеся буквы в списке,если повторяющиxся букв нет - True, а если есть - False, но она всегда выводит True. Вывожу список на экран через set(), но она пишет список с повторяющиемся элементами

```
c = input()
a = [c]
if len(a) == len(set(a)):
    print(set(a),True)
else:
    print(False)
```

вывод
`{'атака'} True`

Comment: а зачем вы делаете `a = [c]`?

Comment: что такое с? наберите a='атака', всё будет работать

Comment: через set() у Вас не может быть повторяющихся элементов, т.к. данный оператор возвращает множество.

Comment: 'c = input()' пропустил строчку

Comment: Зачем здесь вообще `a`? Просто `print(len(c) == len(set(c)))` да и всё

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё потому, что вы вашу строку (которую пользователь вводит) загоняете в список.
`Python` делает `set` не из строки, а из списка `a`, который состоит из одного элемента - строки, которую ввел пользователь.
Как и сказали вам в комментариях достаточно просто сделать так:

```
c = input()
if len(c) == len(set(c)):
    print(set(c), True)
else:
    print(False)
```